# How could I know if the mongodb is started or not by mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a working site with node.js + Express + mongoose.

I am afraid there will be chance that the MongoDB will be shut down by accident or maybe it wasn't  started at first.

The following is the code:

```
var  mongoose    = require('mongoose'),
     Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Test');

var Student = mongoose.model('student', new Schema());

Student.find({...},function(err,docs){
      do sth
});
```

As I see , there will be no err message when `find` in no Mongo situation. It was just blocked.

And I didn't find a property in mongoose to show the connection status.

So anyone know how could I know the status of the mongodb in NodeJs?

Comment: I find a way. when you start mongodb, "http://localhost:27017/" will show the success. So if I want to tell the status in nodejs , I could just request this url and the response.statusCode is what I want.

Comment: Requesting a web url when you already have a connection to the database really doesn't make sense (and success in fetching this doesn't mean the server can't disappear by the time your query executes!).  You can confirm that operations succeed by checking the `err` result and handling exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `err` parameter is a standard [Error object](http://docs.jit.su/articles/errors/what-is-the-error-object) which will be set if there any exceptions such as the database connection being unavailable.  You do not need to check the connection status .. you need to check `err` and handle appropriately.

It would be worth having a read of the [introduction to MongoDB's node driver](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html) for some example usage.

See also [Error handling](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/errors.html) for Mongoose.

Comment: I know, but I couldn't find this kind of function in mongoose 
`db.open(function(err, db) {})`.
If the mongodb is dead , the `find` method just blocked the thread, couln't even execute the callback `function(err,data)`.

Comment: I got it , there is a `mongoose.connect()` , and I could add a callback `function(err)` to check the connection status.